# True or false: $x\neq y$ in a normed vector space, then $\Vert x\Vert \neq \Vert y\Vert$

Tags: solution-verification, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $(\Vert\cdot\Vert,X)$ be a normed vector space. Let $x,y\in X$ be given.

> Claim: If $x\neq y$, then $\Vert x\Vert \neq \Vert y\Vert$.

This is not true in general, because, for instance putting $y=-x$, then $\Vert y\Vert = \Vert -x\Vert=\Vert x\Vert$. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: In case of $\Bbb{R}$ , $\|x\|=|x|$ , it's too trivial that $|•|$ is not injective.

Comment: $\|\lambda x\|=|\lambda|\|x\|$

Comment: Are all of the vectors on the unit sphere equal?

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there! Based on the proposed counter example, you should also consider that $x\neq 0$.